# How do I create a branch without commit history, that links back to where it branched from?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm using this guide: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, as my way to use git with releases. It advises you to use a `develop` and a `master` branch, and for each commit to `master` to be a production ready release.

I've finished version `0.1.0` of my project on my `develop` branch, and tried branching off of that commit with:

```
git checkout --orphan master
```

whilst on the `develop` branch. This worked, and created a new master branch, without prior commit history. *But*, the problem is that this new commit on `master` isn't linked to the `develop` commit it branched from, as visible in my repo's network pane on github. But both branches do seem to be linked in the guide I linked to above.

Is it possible to branch from a commit, and keep the connection between branches but not the commit history? So that I have a single commit to `master`, that still links to where it branched from? Or is that impossible?

Comment: I'm guessing (since it wasn't me), that the downvote was due to the fact that you're asking to do something contradictory.  The "commit history" is precisely the collection of links between commits, so asking to create a commit that links to another but doesn't have history is a contradiction.

Comment: The entire point of the "--orphan" option is to break the commit history.

Comment: @AndrewC, what I don't understand then, is how does the master branch start in this model? The graph doesn't show where it starts.

Comment: I would say that the first blue dot in the upper right (with Tag 0.1) is the one and only origin commit in the repo, and both develop and master split off from there.

Comment: @AndrewC, that's what I thought. But since they don't allow non-production ready commits to the master branch, that means that they developed version 0.1, and then started the repo at 0.1, right?

Comment: Correct.  You have to start somewhere, and I wouldn't read too much into that particular aspect of the diagram.

Comment: @Tonio, I'd say that an answer explaining that these things are contradictory would be more appropriate then, right? Since I did do the research but am just not that familiar with the subject matter, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Yup, I agree. Like I said, I wasn't the one that downvoted! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. It doesn't really make sense for a branch to show the point it branched from *without* showing any history.

Comment: Hmm ok, well I might be misinterpreting the guide then.